# Apache not processing new requests without reaching max_client value.With many idle children

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, ubuntu, tcp

we are facing a problem,that new requests are not processed even if apache hasn't reached its max_client setting.

> Max_client is set to 800
>   max_spare server is 36
>      min_spare
>   server is 35
>   Timeout 300
>   keepalive on
>    keepalive timeout 10
>
> Max_keep_alive_requests 100

Why is apache not processing new requests and sending timeouts evenif it hasnt reached its max_client value.

An strace revealed that around 80+ apache children is in idle state that is 0.0000 seconds in strace ouput.

Why this many children is in idle state and still generating new children,but stillnot processing request and sending timeout.

> we are using Php5,Apache 2 with mpm-prefork,Mysql 5,Running on Ubuntu 11.04 with CSF firewall.

**All the requests are made from single ip(our ip address).**

Will too many request from a single ip result in any TCP/IP or Apache Restrictions to connect,result in denying new requests?

Comment: Could you check error log after restarting apache? in many distributions prefork mode of apache compiled with 256 Limit of MaxClients.

Comment: Not for many versions now - the defaults since 2.2.something are 1024 or 2048 for both.

Answer (score 1):

> Why this many children is in idle state and still generating new
>   children,but stillnot processing request and sending timeout.

"Nobody knows"

First of all, you need to understand that spawning new processes is VERY expensive in prefork.

To avoid doing that whenever possible, you configure the right parameters for your server load and expected traffic peaks.

To find out THAT, you go look at [**server-status**](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_status.html) and check what kind of load this actually is - is it bottlenecking on number of connections, keepalive, per-IP concurrency, bandwidth, backend proxy latencies, too few free processes - what ?

Get back to us if you have enabled server-status (and ExtendedStatus!) and understand what the output means.

Answer (score 0):

it may be that you are sending multiple requests over the same connection from your testbed.

basically you setuped:

```
keepalive on
maxkeepaliverequests 100
```

so in this scenario, if you are generating multiple requests over the same connection, you hit the fan at 100 requests.

try with:

```
keepalive off
```

or

```
maxkeepaliverequests 0
```

note: your ServerLimit setting should also at least match MaxClients

Comment: Already tried with out keepalive but nothing changed...

Comment: do you have some per-ip-address limits somewhere? either apache or maybe iptables?

Comment: also, raise ServerLimit. If it's lower than MaxClients it will be respected.

Comment: server limit is same as that of max_clients..